# Angular Material Mat-List-Option list of checkboxes fetch data

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this list:

```
<mat-selection-list #shoes>
                        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let size of customer.productsizes">
                            {{size .sizeName}}
                        </mat-list-option>
                    </mat-selection-list>
```

The data should come from the data source which is filled in as expected:

[image]

In the rendered output I'm getting blank section, am I missing something in order to get the checkboxes shown with the correct sizeName?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind value as well.

```
<mat-selection-list #shoes>
                    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let size of customer.productsizes" [value]="size.sizeName">
                        {{size.sizeName}}
                    </mat-list-option>
                </mat-selection-list>
```

Replace size.sizeName in value as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, but still the same output.

Comment: I have this now http://prntscr.com/q3qcvw and the checkboxes can't be checked. Let me try to configure stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `changeDetection.onPush` in your App. But using it in the wrong way which is causing this issue, you might see value bind after clicking on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is space between size and .sizename.
If that does not work, Try wrapping the mat-list-option into a div as following

```html
<mat-selection-list>
  <div *ngFor="let size of customer.productsizes">
    <mat-list-option [value]="size.sizeName">{{size.sizeName}}</mat-list-option>
  </div>
</mat-selection-list>
```

If still not working, look at browser console for problem, because it is likely to be a problem with your typescript.